# Как оптимизировать ImageButton

Tags: android-studio, imagebutton

[image: Проблема с мешающим названием]

В обещем, название проекта мешает отображению верхней части этого прекрасного животного. Да и в принципе, как убрать его из отображения и сделать изображение в ImageButton полностью отображаемым?

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="623dp"
            android:background="@drawable/suslik"
            android:onClick="OnLick"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/suslik"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Comment: Пробовали поперебирать варианты значений 'android:scaleType='?

Comment: Пробовал, особо ничего это не изменило, к сожалению.